# Pass block of code as parameter and execute in try catch

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

TL;DR: I'd like to pass some code that will then be executed within a try catch
Pseudo code:

```
void ExecuteInTryCatch(BlockOfCode)
{
   try
   {
      execute BlockOfCode with possible return value
   }
   catch (MyException e)
   {
      do something
   }
}
```

Long Version: I'm writing automation tests of a web application and would like to execute some code that will catch certain exceptions that may result from non-deterministic reasons and retry executing that code for a certain time out before finally throwing the exception. I've looked at possibly using a delegate for this purpose but am pretty confused how I would accomplish this and I've never used lambda expressions and that's even more confusing.

The goal is to be able to reuse this code for various selenium actions. This is fairly simply with Ruby but not so much in C#, personally.

Comment: Have you tried using delegates?

Comment: Think of a lambda expression as a bit like a block in Ruby.  (More accurately, it's like a `Proc` object in Ruby; `a = lambda { puts "hello world" }` in Ruby is about the same as `Action a = () => { Console.WriteLine("hello world"); }` in C#.)

Comment: There are *lots* of resources available on the subject; it seems that you haven't even *tried* to solve the problem.  There are books, online tutorials, blogs, stack overflow questions, classes, and all sorts of other resources on this.

Comment: I've found this (using a function to wrap some lambda in common logging/error-handling) to be a not-uncommon pattern in C#.  It may not be obvious to a complete C# neophyte - indeed, it's not obvious to some professional C# devs... :-\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to the other answer: if you need a return value, use Func instead of Action.

```
// method definition...
T ExecuteInTryCatch<T>(Func<T> block)
{
    try
    {
        return block();
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        // handle e
    }
}

// using the method...
int three = ExecuteInTryCatch(() => { return 3; })
```

Answer (score 6):

```
void ExecuteInTryCatch(Action code)
{
   try
   {
       code();
   }
   catch (MyException e)
   {
      do something
   }
}

ExecuteInTryCatch( ()=>{
    // stuff here
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `Func` rather than `Action`?  OP indicates a possible return value.

Comment: @john they could always use multiple overloads - but "possible return value" doesnt really work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the code return a value, use a Func

```
T ExecuteInTryCatch<T>(Func<T> codeBlock)
{
    try
    {
        codeBlock();
    }
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        //Do Something
    }
 }
```

otherwise use am Action

```
void ExecuteInTryCatch(Action codeBlock)
{
   try
   {
       codeBlock();
   }
   catch (MyException e)
   {
       //Do Something
   }
}
```

You can go even future and define your own delegates to restrict the expressions that are passed in.